# Parameter declaration List. should be a vector in Clojure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clojure

I'm trying to do my CS lab for my class, but every time I try running my tests vs. my code, my code never loads up. It shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration List. should be a vector
at clojure.core$assert_valid_fdecl.invoke(core.clj:6567)
at clojure.core$sigs.invoke(core.clj:220)
at clojure.core$defn.doInvoke(core.clj:294)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:494)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:431)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1(Compiler.java:6366)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand(Compiler.java:6427)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6495)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6952)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:359)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:350)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:429)
```

Here is my code sorry guys. I have no idea what is wrong, everything looks right to me.

```
(ns linked_list_lab.core)

;; We start with a defrecord.  In traditional lisps, the
;; first element of a list is called the "car", standing for
;; "Contents of Address Register," the name of the register where
;; it was stored.  The pointer to the rest of the list was called
;; the "cdr," for "Contents of Decrement Register", and is pronounced
;; "could-er".

(defrecord Cons [car cdr])

;; One problem with singly linked lists is that finding the length is
;; expensive $${\cal O}(n)$$.  We can use a wrapper class to deal with
;; that.  Here we have a `List` record that keeps a pointer to the list
;; along with the size.

(defrecord List [data size])

;; The `make-list` function just creates an empty list.

(defn make-list
  "Create an empty list."
  (List. nil 0))

;; The `insert-front` function shows a special syntax Clojure has.
;; If you know the argument to your function should be a record or a
;; hash-map, you can use this pattern-matching syntax as a shorthand.
;; Here we have `{:keys [data size]}`, which will create new variables
;; `data` and `size`.  So if I pass in `{:data 10 :size 20}`, then
;; `data` will be given 10, and `size` will be given 20.
;; This is often called "destructuring".

;; Test broke-1 will not increment the size.
;; Test broke-2 will forget to do the cons.
;; Test broke-3 will replace the cons and not point to the next one.

(defn insert-front 
  "Insert an element at the beginning of the list."
  [{:keys [data size]} new-elt]
  (List. (Cons. new-elt data) (+ 1 size))) 

;; Here are some utility functions that convert Clojure lists to
;; our Cons. record, and vice-versa.  The broke versions will not
;; mess with these.

(defn list-to-cons
  [xx]
  (cond (empty? xx) nil
        :else       (Cons. (first xx) (list-to-cons (next xx)))))

 (defn cons-to-list
  [xx]
  (cond (nil? xx)   '() 
        :else       (cons (:car xx) (cons-to-list (:cdr xx)))))

;; The `insert-sorted` function assumes that the elements are orderable
;; and puts the element in the spot that will preserve the ordering.

;; Test broke-4 will use `(Cons. elt (:cdr xx))` in the third case.
;; Test broke-5 will use `(Cons. (:car xx) nil)` in the second case.

(defn insert-ordered-cons
  "Insert the element `elt` into an ordered `Cons.` chain.
This is used by `insert-ordered`."
  [elt xx]
  (cond (empty? xx) (Cons. elt nil)
        (> elt (:car xx)) (Cons. (:car xx) (insert-ordered-cons elt (:cdr xx)))
        :fine-be-that-way (Cons. elt xx)))

(defn insert-ordered
  "Insert an element into an ordered list."
  [{:keys [data size]} new-elt]
  (List. (insert-ordered-cons new-elt data) (+ size 1)))

;; The `delete` function will delete one element from the list.

;; Test broke-6 will truncate the list past the deletion point.
;; Test broke-7 will forget to decrement the size.
;; Test broke-8 will always decrement the size, even if the element is not found.

(defn delete
  "Delete `elt` from `xx`."
  [elt xx]
   (cond (empty? xx) nil
       (= elt (:car xx)) (:cdr xx)
        :else (Cons. (:car xx) (delete elt (:cdr xx))) )
  )

;; The `delete-all` function will delete all copies of elt from xx.

;; Test broke-9 will delete only one copy.
;; Test broke-10 will decrement the count instead of properly subtracting the
;;      number of deletions.

(defn delete-all
  "Delete all occurrences of `elt` from `xx`."
  [elt xx]
  (cond (empty? xx) nil
      (= elt (:car xx))  (delete-all elt (:cdr xx))
        :else (Cons. (:car xx) (delete-all elt (:cdr xx)))
        )
  )
```

Comment: As a rule, show your code, not just the error.

Comment: Also, in terms of writing good questions, a title of `Parameter declaration List. should be a vector in Clojure` would be a lot more useful than `I don't understand what this error means`.

Comment: tonyisapony, as the "How to ..." link suggests, the first step with this sort of mysterious problem is to try evaluating different parts of the code separately, either in the REPL or by commenting or deleting sections.  Often, you'll discover the solution that way.  If you'd done that, you'd know that the problem was with the def of `make-list`, even if you still didn't know what the problem was.  At that point, you would be able to ask a more specific question.

Comment: (ns linked_list_lab.core) should probably be (ns linked-list-lab.core). This idiosyncrasy is described here: http://clojure.org/reference/libs "Hyphens in the lib name are replaced by underscores in the path"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `make-list` misses a parameter declaration vector.

```
(defn make-list
  [] ;; <- fix
  ...)
```

Comment: Oh my god!! thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: The best Clojure advise ever!!!

Answer (score 5):

You are doing a defn without a parameter list.